# Many-to-Many Relationship

Tags: model-view-controller, many-to-many, orchardcms

I have been trying to "manufacture" a many-to-many relation module between content items in Orchard. Unfortunately, with no success. But then I got an idea of how to simulate such a relationship WITH TAGS. Basically, I have to relate a "project" content type/part with a "member" type/part. Here is my idea :

Create a "project" content type, and attach a tag part to it. Create a list of project type.

Create a "member" content type, and attach a tag part to it. Create a list of member type.

Add a container widget on the projects page, in which you show the elements of the list of project type, but in the view add a filter that only shows the content items that have a "project-xx" tag(project-x being the tag on(of) the current project). The only problem I see so far is :

How can I access the tag of another content part/type on the page, so as to use it in a view(access the "project" tags from within the "member" view ) ?

**Any** idea on this or **any other idea** on modeling a many-to-many relationship between content items in Orchard 1.1 would be appreciated. I have read the docs, but have not managed the create a n-n relationship between content items.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but have you seen Mechanics module (http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Downplay.Mechanics)?

This allows you to create connections between content items. However, it doesn't work with more recent versions of Orchard (I think >= 1.5). Worth a try if you are still using 1.1